# How to calculate user defined SNR, given only sampling frequency and a vector containing signal samples?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

So I have the samples (hex values) of a sinus signal and I know the sampling frequency. Using this I can plot an fft or periodogram but then I would like to find out the SNR ratio. What would be the most accurate way to calculate the noise and signal power? I would prefer doing it in frequency domain. Is there a way to do this also in time domain?

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: @schwartz, sorry, posted to the wrong question.  Thanks for not downvoting it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if there is noise on your signal and you know that your underlying signal is a sine wave, you can easily get your signal parameters i.e. amplitude,frequency and phase by least squares. If y(t) is your signal just minimize the L2 norm of (y(t)-A.sin(wt+b)) over A,w and b. Then you can easily get signal power from the underlying signal and the noise power from the error signal (y(t)-A.sin(wt+b)).